# where do i start with an app that's going to hold a database on ios/android?

Tags: android, ios, database

i want to contribute to a fandom i'm in and also practice my coding, so i wanted to make an app that would let the user keep track of the event stories they've read. but i don't know where to start with this.

i can add extra features like scoring and total stories read later on, but for now i need an idea of where to start. i think i've heard java would work for this? but would that even work on android and ios both??

once i know what programming language to use i need to find something to code this on, as well as how to even hold information in a database. (similar to myanimelist and how it has a database of entries that you can add to your own list.) likely with a login system--but one step at a time.

what are the basics i need to know to start? and where would i build this app? thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but this is way to vague to fit this site.  If you had a specific question like "How do I connect to a local database in Android" it would be on topic.  "How do I write an app" is far too large a topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single application that can work on both ios and android then go for [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) or [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/). For your question regarding where to keep database and how login system works you will need to study at-least one of the systems in some depth.